# how to export a modified kernel header

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I modified some files in the Linux kernel

```
include/linux/tcp.h
include/net/tcp.h 
net/ipv4/sysctl_net_ipv4.c
net/ipv4/tcp_output.c
```

Following this i compiled the modified Linux kernel

```
$ make modules_install  
$ make headers_install INSTALL_HDR_PATH=/usr/include  
$ make install
```

The new kernel can start, everything seems normal. But when i tried to include the modified kernel header in my app, the compiler complains that the header does NOT define the types which i have just added. Upon checking `/usr/include/netinet/tcp.h`, i find that it is NOT the file i modified.

> Q. **How can i properly export modified Linux kernel headers to include in a C program** ?

Comment: in my app, i use this: #include <netinet/tcp.h>, but the tcp.h is not my modification file

Comment: `/usr/include/linux/tcp.h` and `/usr/include/netinet/tcp.h` are both separate files. Can you try using `#include <linux/tcp.h>` in your C program and see if it works properly?...

Comment: I need to get clarify have u ran a command `make` before make modules_install

Comment: yes, i make -j5, make moudles_install, make headers_install, and make install. i don't know how to update the system's header file to my modification file. but i found another way to compile my c app, i added TCP_CWND type in <netinet/tcp.h>, i stil include the old version header of <netinet/tcp.h>, but i added "#define TCP_CWND 19"

Comment: to my c app, it can work, i still don't know how to update the header file, but this way can compile my c app, and the C app run properly.

Comment: TheCodeArtist,first thank you to help me editing my question. I just modified /netinet/tcp.h, i don't modify linux/tcp.h, so it doesn't work if i include <linux/tcp.h>. thank you for you help

Answer (score 1):

A. Copy them to somewhere the code expects to find them, such as a directory you then pass to the compiler via `-I`, and then make sure that the code actually includes them.

Answer (score 1):

As you are changing some linux header, do a make first to see whether there are any side effects. The kernel might not compile. This is absolutely necessary.

I think make is also necessary for the changes to take effect for the kernel headers so that they can be exported to user space.

Just doing make modules_install will install already built modules, the modules won't be recompiled against the changed headers. Similarly for other install commands.

Comment: yes, i am sure the modification has effects, i can use sysctl -w to set my new option of the kernel setting. it can works.

Answer (score 0):

The right location of `INSTALL_HDR_PATH` should be `/usr` instead:

```
$ make headers_install INSTALL_HDR_PATH=/usr
```