# Install modified Linux header files in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, header-files

I downloaded a kernel package and modified it by myself. The new kernel works well now but when I want to write the user-space codes, problem occurs because the new macros defined in my kernel cannot be found. I find this is because the user-space code still include the header files from `/usr/include/`. I have tried `sudo make headers_install_all INSTALL_HDR_PATH=/usr` (as well as `make headers_install`) but it still installs old header files into `/usr/include` (I remove `linux/socket.h` deliberately before making and find a new file is generated, which is not the one after modification).

I find this post as well: [how to export a modified kernel header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18879972/how-to-export-a-modified-kernel-header) and it's almost the same problem as mine. Unfortunately I didn't find a solution there other than modify the system header files manually.

The command I used to compile the kernel is:

```
$ make
$ make modules_install  
$ make headers_install INSTALL_HDR_PATH=/usr  
$ make install
```

I also checked that `PATH2MY_KERNEL/include/` indeed contains the modified header files, which should be the ones used to compile my kernel.

Any idea how to update the system kernel header files with mine? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What path (relative from top kernel source directory) to the header file is? Note, that only headers under `include/uapi/linux/` and under others `uapi/` subdirectories are intended to be included by the user.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for reply! The `socket.h` is under `include/linux/` in my repository. But I also checked `/usr/include/uapi/` and find it is empty. In my repository, there are actually several files under this folder, ie. `include/uapi/`.

Comment: I mean that resulted header file `/usr/include/socket.h` is originated from `include/uapi/linux/socket.h` in your kernel, not a `include/linux/socket.h`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you sooooooo much!! Yes this works for me perfectly now!